# Efficient element-wise multiplication in Python with numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, integer-overflow

I have a numpy array of type np.int64, to which I am trying to apply a formula.

Let's say the array is a 2D array called `total_img` which has dimensions 400 X 300 pixels. For each pixel I want to compute the following formula. `px = 255*(min - px)/(min - max)`. I want these rescaled pixels to be stored always in `total_img`. How can I efficiently implement this using numpy arrays?

Note, `min` and `max` are simply the 1th percentile and 99th percentile values and are actually stored as floats. Should I convert them to ints for better accuracy (remember total_img is of type np.int64 - No Overflow will ever occur). Also min will most likely be negative.

I was using:

```
for row in total_img:
    for px in row:        
        px = 255*(min-px)/(min - max)
```

Comment: you should not shadow builtins such as min/max ... just an aside totally unrelated to your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
total_img = 255*(min - total_img)/(min - max)
```

You literally just plug in `total_img` instead of `px`, and it does the operation elementwise. If you want to store the result into the original `total_img` instead of replacing it, you can slice-assign:

```
total_img[:] = 255*(min - total_img)/(min - max)
```

but note that this doesn't actually save any time or memory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could directly do this:

```
total_img = 255*(min-total_img)/(min - max)
```